# C++ using an unordered key combination for a map lookup

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I want to create an `unordered_map`, where the key is a combination of two integers. As the key values order shall be ignored when comparing, I thought of using an `unordered_set` as key like this:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    unordered_set<int> key_set1 = {21, 42};
    unordered_map<unordered_set<int>, char> map;
    map[key_set1] = 'a';
    ...
    unordered_set<int> key_set2 = {42, 21};
    if(map[key_set2] == map[key_set2])
        success();
}
```

On compile time it looks like some problem with the hash function:

```
error: no match for call to ‘(const std::hash<std::unordered_set<int> >) (const std::unordered_set<int>&)’
  noexcept(declval<const _Hash&>()(declval<const _Key&>()))>
```

How can I solve this? Or is there a better way/data structure?

Comment: you would probably want std::pair of ints, but you'd need to add a hash for this. Or change your key to be a 64bit int and combine your 2 ints to 1 64bit int

Comment: Using a `set` as the key here would serve no purpose other than to slow down your program.

Comment: The purpose is, that the key values can be unordered. So the comparison down in my answer would be true.

Comment: @Corbie oops, that makes sense :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out earlier to use `std::pair` directly as a key you would need to explicitly define a hash function for it. If you want to avoid that, you can just do a bit-wise combination of 2 unsigned integers into 1:

```
uint64_t makeKey(uint32_t a, uint32_t b)
{
    return a < b ? (static_cast<uint64_t>(a) << 32) + b : (static_cast<uint64_t>(b) << 32) + a;
}

int main ()
{
    auto key_set1 = makeKey(21, 42);

    unordered_map<uint64_t, char> map;
    map[key_set1] = 'a';
    //...

    auto key_set2 = makeKey(42, 21);
    if(map[key_set1] == map[key_set2])
        std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: This is not helpful for trying to lookup the keys in a random order, but sorting them first seems so be the most performant way ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There is no predefined hash function for an `unordered_set` so you have to implement your own; there's documentation for that here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash.

Basically you'd need:

```
// custom specialization of std::hash can be injected in namespace std
namespace std
{
    template<> struct hash<unordered_set<int>>
    {
        std::size_t operator()(unordered_set<int> const& s) const
        {
            std::size_t hash = 0;
            for (auto && i : s) hash ^= std::hash<int>()(i);
            return hash;
        }
    };
}
```

Now `xor` isn't the recommended way to combine hash functions, but it should work in this case specifically because it's both **unordered** and **set**. Because it's unordered you need a function that's commutative. The recommended hash combiners don't have this property as you usually want "abc" to hash differently than "bca". Secondly the fact that it's a set insures that you won't have any duplicate elements. This saves your hash function from failing because `x ^ x == 0`.

I should also mention that you want to define this in the cpp file so you don't expose this specific hash implementation on std types to everyone.

Comment: This is actually very helpful. Although I think ordering and combining the keys to a single one is more performant.

Comment: If your key is always a pair then that's definitely the better solution. You might want to define an `unordered_pair` type to make your intention clearer. Or `using unordered_key = uint64_t`.

Comment: I think you have UB to specialize `hash` not for your type.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that unordered_set is not built for being used as a key in an unordered container.

If you always use exactly two ints, it would be more economical for you to use a pair of ints as a key, and add a function that makes a properly ordered pair from two integers:

```
pair<int,int> unordered_key(int a, int b) {
    return a<b?make_pair(a, b):make_pair(b, a);
}
```

Comment: But he has said the order of the integers does not matter.

Comment: (I take that to mean that the unorderedness of the integers _does_ matter)

Comment: if it don't matter then using a pair is better... so why would it matter?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The pair used as a key will be in a specific order, so the order of parameters to unordered_key would not matter.

Comment: Okay this is much clearer with the code example now.

Comment: Unfortunately this results in the same problem. The pair can also not be used as key for the map, as there is no proper hash function.

Answer (score 1):

Since the order is not important here, you can use `std::pair` with a customized factory to force the order of the two integers:

```
std::pair<int, int> make_my_pair(int x, int y) {
    return std::make_pair(std::min(x, y), std::max(x, y));
}
```

Of course this is only going to work if you use `make_my_pair` consistently.

Alternatively you can define your own key class that has a similar property.

Comment: This results in the same problem. The pair can also not be used as key for the map, as there is no proper hash function.

Comment: Well my understanding is that you want to use `unordered_map` because order is not important, but you can use `map` for this as well, as long as the key is properly defined. Of course unless there's other reasons for choosing the unordered containers.